# how do I code a button with animated background ? (React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, user-experience

I would like to create a button with animated(gif/video) background

here is an example - the DOWNLOAD button on this sites main page: https://fivem.net/

Preferably I would like to see a solution using React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in CSS:

backgroundImage: `url('animated-gif-url.gif')`